# how to get all the data from database from 3 tables?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, full-outer-join

My problem is, i am getting the datas which is present in all the 3 tables.But i want to display the data which is not present in any one of the table(that is empty space or 0 is printed on that item if it's not present in anyone of the table)..i googled and found that it can be done by fullouter join but i don't know how to use it..
Controller Code:

```
   public function St_statement(){

        $startdate = $this->input->post('SDate');
        $enddate = $this->input->post('EDate');
        $date = str_replace('/', '-', $startdate);
        $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
        $date2 = str_replace('/', '-', $enddate);
        $newDate2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date2));
        $data['startdate'] = $startdate;
        $data['enddate'] = $enddate;
        if ($this->input->post('all'))
        {
        $this->db->where('billdate >=', $newDate);
        $this->db->where('billdate <=', $newDate2);
        $this->db->where('billdte >=', $newDate);
        $this->db->where('billdte <=', $newDate2);
        $this->db->select("Item");
        $this->db->select("pgroup");
        $this->db->select_sum("Stock");
        $this->db->select_sum("quantity");
        $this->db->select_sum("Qty");
        $this->db->from('opstock');
        $this->db->group_by("Item");
        $this->db->order_by("pgroup",'asc');

        $this->db->join('purchaseitem',' purchaseitem.Prdtname = opstock.Item','OUTER');
         $this->db->join('salesitem','salesitem.Prdtname =  purchaseitem.Prdtname','OUTER');
          $this->db->join('itemmaster','itemmaster.itemname =  purchaseitem.Prdtname','OUTER');
         $this->db->join('pgroup','pgroup.pgroupid = itemmaster.catcode','OUTER');

        $query = $this->db->get();
  $data['query'] = $query;

        $this->load->view('Inventory/St_Stmt', $data);
        //$this->load->view('Inventory/St_Stmt1', $data);
    }
    if($this->input->post('selected'))
    {
        if($name = $this->input->post('businessType'))
        {
        $this->db->where('billdate >=', $newDate);
        $this->db->where('billdate <=', $newDate2);
        $this->db->where('billdte >=', $newDate);
        $this->db->where('billdte <=', $newDate2);
        $this->db->where('pgroup',$name);
        $this->db->select("Item");
        $this->db->select("pgroup");
        $this->db->select_sum("Stock");
        $this->db->select_sum("quantity");
        $this->db->select_sum("Qty");
        $this->db->from('opstock');
        $this->db->group_by("Item");

        $this->db->join('purchaseitem',' purchaseitem.Prdtname = opstock.Item','OUTER');
         $this->db->join('salesitem','salesitem.Prdtname =  purchaseitem.Prdtname','OUTER');
          $this->db->join('itemmaster','itemmaster.itemname =  purchaseitem.Prdtname','OUTER');
         $this->db->join('pgroup','pgroup.pgroupid = itemmaster.catcode','OUTER');

        $query = $this->db->get();
  $data['query'] = $query;

        $this->load->view('Inventory/St_Stmt', $data);


    }

}
}
```

Comment: Hi. You are just asking us to write yet another presentation of outer join, plus a bespoke tutorial. That is too broad a question. And it is a faq because of all the other people who asked without researching or searching. Find a presentation & ask a specific question where you are stuck. Google your question. If you still need to ask then please read & act on [mcve]. Also your text is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of an example to clearly express what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

$query = "SELECT `Item`, `pgroup`, SUM(`Stock`) AS `Stock`, SUM(`quantity`) AS `quantity`, SUM(`Qty`) AS `Qty` FROM `opstock` 
LEFT JOIN `purchaseitem` ON `purchaseitem`.`Prdtname` = `opstock`.`Item` 
LEFT JOIN `salesitem` ON `salesitem`.`Prdtname` = `purchaseitem`.`Prdtname` 
LEFT JOIN `itemmaster` ON `itemmaster`.`itemname` = `purchaseitem`.`Prdtname` 
LEFT JOIN `pgroup` ON `pgroup`.`pgroupid` = `itemmaster`.`catcode` WHERE `billdate` >= '".$newDate."' AND `billdate` <= '".$newDate2."' AND `billdte` >= '".$newDate."' AND `billdte` <= '".$newDate2."' GROUP BY `Item` ORDER BY `pgroup` ASC
UNION
SELECT `Item`, `pgroup`, SUM(`Stock`) AS `Stock`, SUM(`quantity`) AS `quantity`, SUM(`Qty`) AS `Qty` FROM `opstock` 
RIGHT JOIN `purchaseitem` ON `purchaseitem`.`Prdtname` = `opstock`.`Item` 
LEFT JOIN `salesitem` ON `salesitem`.`Prdtname` = `purchaseitem`.`Prdtname` 
LEFT JOIN `itemmaster` ON `itemmaster`.`itemname` = `purchaseitem`.`Prdtname` 
LEFT JOIN `pgroup` ON `pgroup`.`pgroupid` = `itemmaster`.`catcode` WHERE `billdate` >= '".$newDate."' AND `billdate` <= '".$newDate2."' AND `billdte` >= '".$newDate."' AND `billdte` <= '".$newDate2."' GROUP BY `Item` ORDER BY `pgroup` ASC
SELECT `Item`, `pgroup`, SUM(`Stock`) AS `Stock`, SUM(`quantity`) AS `quantity`, SUM(`Qty`) AS `Qty` FROM `opstock` 
LEFT JOIN `purchaseitem` ON `purchaseitem`.`Prdtname` = `opstock`.`Item` 
RIGHT JOIN `salesitem` ON `salesitem`.`Prdtname` = `purchaseitem`.`Prdtname` 
LEFT JOIN `itemmaster` ON `itemmaster`.`itemname` = `purchaseitem`.`Prdtname` 
LEFT JOIN `pgroup` ON `pgroup`.`pgroupid` = `itemmaster`.`catcode` WHERE `billdate` >= '".$newDate."' AND `billdate` <= '".$newDate2."' AND `billdte` >= '".$newDate."' AND `billdte` <= '".$newDate2."' GROUP BY `Item` ORDER BY `pgroup` ASC
UNION
SELECT `Item`, `pgroup`, SUM(`Stock`) AS `Stock`, SUM(`quantity`) AS `quantity`, SUM(`Qty`) AS `Qty` FROM `opstock` 
LEFT JOIN `purchaseitem` ON `purchaseitem`.`Prdtname` = `opstock`.`Item` 
LEFT JOIN `salesitem` ON `salesitem`.`Prdtname` = `purchaseitem`.`Prdtname` 
RIGHT JOIN `itemmaster` ON `itemmaster`.`itemname` = `purchaseitem`.`Prdtname` 
LEFT JOIN `pgroup` ON `pgroup`.`pgroupid` = `itemmaster`.`catcode` WHERE `billdate` >= '".$newDate."' AND `billdate` <= '".$newDate2."' AND `billdte` >= '".$newDate."' AND `billdte` <= '".$newDate2."' GROUP BY `Item` ORDER BY `pgroup` ASC";

$query = $this->db->query($query);

Comment: Please look at the edited version of your post before you post. Please click on 'edit' & read the edit help & format properly. Please read [ask] & [answer]--this question is too broad & unclear & a faq duplicate & shouldn't be answered. And when answering please don't just dump code. PS There is no full outer join in MySQL.

Comment: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN purchaseitem ON purchaseitem.Prdtname = opstock.Item FULL OUTER JOIN ' at line 1

Comment: SELECT Item, pgroup, SUM(Stock) AS Stock, SUM(quantity) AS quantity, SUM(Qty) AS Qty FROM opstock FULL OUTER JOIN purchaseitem ON purchaseitem.Prdtname = opstock.Item FULL OUTER JOIN salesitem ON salesitem.Prdtname = purchaseitem.Prdtname FULL OUTER JOIN itemmaster ON itemmaster.itemname = purchaseitem.Prdtname FULL OUTER JOIN pgroup ON pgroup.pgroupid = itemmaster.catcode WHERE billdate >= '1' AND billdate <= '1' AND billdte >= '2018-11-15' AND billdte <= '2018-11-15' GROUP BY Item ORDER BY pgroup ASC

Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/Yuva/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: @esakkichandra MySQL does not have full outer join syntax. See my comments on this answer & the question.

Comment: Have you looked at the formatted version of your post?

Comment: @MacRathod it shows an error Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY